# using math under interval in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals

The query below does not work

> missing right parenthesis

but you know what I need to get, so how I can get it to work?
how should I write it!

```
SELECT sysdate,
       (sysdate + interval (to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 2011) YEAR) as tt
FROM dual;
```

I was thinking of this solution

```
SELECT sysdate,
       add_months(sysdate,12*(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 2011))
FROM dual;
```

is it a correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  Are there error messages?  Does a rabid wolverine crawl out of your monitor and maul your face whenever you try to run it?  **Be more specific, please.**

Comment: @Data-Base - I'm an Oracle SQL developer and it's not obvious to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Is the goal to add 1 year to SYSDATE if the query is run in 2012, 2 years if the query is run in 2013, etc.?

Comment: you got it right, yes! well I'm working on migrating views from mysql to oracle, so I'm ending up with these strange issues :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you to what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    sysdate,
    (sysdate + TO_YMINTERVAL((to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 2011)||'-0')) as tt
FROM dual;
```

Note the appending of the "-0" is necessary, since there is no Year interval, it has years and months (the "-0" indicates 0 months).

It should also be noted that this will cause problems on leap day, since Feb 29 doesn't exist next year.

I would solve this problem by converting your years to months (multiply by 12) and using add_months:

```
SELECT
    sysdate,
    add_months(sysdate, (to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 2011)*12) as tt
FROM dual;
```

Which on leap day will return 2/28/2013 for tt.

Comment: your solution suits my needs better :-) thanks again for the help